# Given simple type T, get array type T[]

Tags: .net, arrays, reflection, types

How can I get the type of `Array of type T` given `T` ?

LinqPad-friendly snippet below:

```
void Main()
{
    Type t = typeof(string);
    Type tArray = GetArrayType(t);
    tArray.Dump(); // System.String[]
}
Type GetArrayType(Type t)
{
    ////this is cheating !!
    //return typeof(string[]); 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
type.MakeArrayType()
```

eg:

```
int a = 123;
Type aType = a.GetType();
Type aArrayType = aType.MakeArrayType();

// aArrayType.FullName = "System.Int32[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

I *knew* there's [a better way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc2e4ft8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :)

```
Type GetArrayType(Type t){
    return t.MakeArrayType();
}
```

### Original answer:

This works, but I'm hoping for something less hacky

```
Type GetArrayType(Type t){
    return Type.GetType(t + "[]");
}
```

Comment: This is what I'd do...